# Unable to load Module Parsing Error

Tags: parsing

I get a parsing error when going to .
I have tried putting this problem on TechNet but still no answer.

Below is the Event ID that I get when I go to this internal website.
I have redacted the following to strip out personal info.

```
fiLog Name:      Application

Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0

Date:          2/5/2015 12:12:23 PM

Event ID:      1310

Task Category: Web Event

Level:         Warning

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A

Computer:      SERVERNAME.domain.local

Description:

Event code: 3006

Event message: A parser error has occurred.

Event time: 2/5/2015 12:12:23 PM

Event time (UTC): 2/5/2015 8:12:23 PM

Event ID: 1b2df808c7be47d39e7a57e3085a5239

Event sequence: 17

Event occurrence: 3

Event detail code: 0



Application information:

    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130676406758832527

    Trust level: Full

    Application Virtual Path: /

    Application Path: C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\WebApps\CertWebService\

    Machine name: SERVERNAME



Process information:

    Process ID: 10296

    Process name: w3wp.exe

    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE



Exception information:

    Exception type: HttpParseException

    Exception message: Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Client.Website.Default'.

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)

   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Client.Website.Default'.

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)

Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Client.Website.Default'.

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)





Request information:

    Request URL: http://localhost:65510/connect/default.aspx

    Request path: /connect/default.aspx

    User host address: ::1

    User: 

    Is authenticated: False

    Authentication Type: 

    Thread account name: DOMAIN\ADMIN



Thread information:

    Thread ID: 6

    Thread account name: DOMAIN\ADMIN

    Is impersonating: False

    Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)

   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)





Custom event details:  Event Xml:

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">

  <System>

    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />

    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1310</EventID>

    <Level>3</Level>

    <Task>3</Task>

    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>

    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-02-05T20:12:23.000000000Z" />

    <EventRecordID>608248</EventRecordID>

    <Channel>Application</Channel>

    <Computer>SERVERNAME.domain.local</Computer>

    <Security />

  </System>

  <EventData>

    <Data>3006</Data>

    <Data>A parser error has occurred.</Data>

    <Data>2/5/2015 12:12:23 PM</Data>

    <Data>2/5/2015 8:12:23 PM</Data>

    <Data>1b2df808c7be47d39e7a57e3085a5239</Data>

    <Data>17</Data>

    <Data>3</Data>

    <Data>0</Data>

    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130676406758832527</Data>

    <Data>Full</Data>

    <Data>/</Data>

    <Data>C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\WebApps\CertWebService\</Data>

    <Data>SERVERNAMEfi</Data>

    <Data>

    </Data>

    <Data>10296</Data>

    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>

    <Data>NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE</Data>

    <Data>HttpParseException</Data>

    <Data>Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Client.Website.Default'.

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)

   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)

Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Client.Website.Default'.

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)

Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Client.Website.Default'.

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)

</Data>

    <Data>http://localhost:65510/connect/default.aspx</Data>

    <Data>/connect/default.aspx</Data>

    <Data>::1</Data>

    <Data>

    </Data>

    <Data>False</Data>

    <Data>

    </Data>

    <Data>DOMAIN\ADMIN</Data>

    <Data>6</Data>

    <Data>DOMAIN\ADMIN</Data>

    <Data>False</Data>

    <Data>   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)

   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)

   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)

   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)

</Data>

  </EventData>

</Event>

Susan E. Russel
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on an application I am working on.
It is an ASP.NET forms application.  The application was limped along for years and nobody could run it from their workstation. It started as a .NET 2.0 framework and they never went to 4.0 framework because of this and other software quality issues. They only compiled individual components and deployed to the web server.  UGH

So I followed these steps:
1). I created a new C# ASP.NET Empty Forms project.

2). I ran the project and saw the directory browse load just fine.

Directory Listing -- /

---

```
Friday, February 20, 2015 06:04 PM        <dir> bin  
Friday, February 20, 2015 06:04 PM        <dir> obj  
Friday, February 20, 2015 06:04 PM        <dir> Properties   
Friday, February 20, 2015 06:04 PM          309 Web.config  
Friday, February 20, 2015 06:04 PM        1,285 Web.Debug.config  
Friday, February 20, 2015 06:04 PM        1,346 Web.Release.config  
Friday, February 20, 2015 06:04 PM        3,995 WebApplication1.csproj  
Friday, February 20, 2015 06:04 PM        1,086 WebApplication1.csproj.user
```

====================================================================
3). Add New Item Web Form, and I "Set As Start Page"

4). I copied all the html from the  to the  tags in the webpage with the error to this new webpage.

5). In the code behind inside the Public Partial Class section (Here)

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page  
{  
=== HERE ===  
}
```

5a). I copied the entire code module about 3000 lines of code.

6). I added the using statements that are required.

7). I added the reference to the .NET library if it was not attached.

8). Mine used a web service so I set a reference to that.

Presto the web page runs with out the parsing error.

I think it was some setting in the old csproj file.